# Moosend: Error with Syntax (Javascript) on WP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've been battling this for a little while and I'm a bit lost as to where to go to fix this. Moosend cannot help.

I'm following their article: https://help.moosend.com/hc/en-us/articles/4413852278162

I've de-minified the code, however wordpress still claims the following:

`Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 65 of file wp-content/themes/medigreen/header.php. Please fix and try saving again.`

`syntax error, unexpected token ",", expecting variable`

I've got enough experience to classify myself as an intermediate JS developer, but I don't see anything wrong with the code block.

```
!(function (t, n, e, o, a) {
    function d(t) {
        var n = ~~(Date.now() / 3e5),
            o = document.createElement(e);
        (o.async = !0), (o.src = t + "?ts=" + n);
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
        a.parentNode.insertBefore(o, a);
    }
    (t.MooTrackerObject = a),
        (t[a] =
            t[a] ||
            function () {
                return t[a].q ? void t[a].q.push(arguments) : void (t[a].q = [arguments]);
            }),
        window.attachEvent ? window.attachEvent("onload", d.bind(this, o)) : window.addEventListener("load", d.bind(this, o), !1);
})(window, document, "script", "//cdn.stat-track.com/statics/moosend-tracking.min.js", "mootrack");
```

Comment: Which is line 65?

Comment: Sorry, line 65 is !(function (t, n, e, o, a) {

Comment: What's the rest of the code? Can you show what comes before this? From the error, it looks like you might be putting javascript in a PHP block.

Comment: You fixed it without even really trying! I was putting the code in the PHP section, not Javascript. Nice! Thanks :)